# Log4j 2.6 warning for a null message factory

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

After upgrading to log4j2 version 2.6, I face these warnings:

```
2016-06-06 16:36:14,920 localhost-startStop-1 WARN The Logger foo.bar was created with the message factory org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.MessageFactory2Adapter@437958b6 and is now requested with a null message factory (defaults to org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedMessageFactory), which may create log events with unexpected formatting.
```

It was ok in version 2.5, any comments ?!

*I see the log messages in appenders*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the Log4j 2.6 release. It has been fixed (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1407) and will be fixed in the upcoming 2.6.1 release (which is now being reviewed and should be live in ~48 hours).

It is not a real problem, the bug is that the warning is shown unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks for this real quick fix!

Comment: I have been trying to figure out what was preventing my logging from working. If only I had see this earlier, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

mostly because the logger is created as a instance object, not static object, like this:

```
public class PropertiesConfigurationFactory {
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
}
```

when create PropertiesConfigurationFactory again, logger is also created.

in LoggerContext it will get the created instance of logger

```
getLogger(name, null)
```

null is MessageFactory

so it will check the null with the old logger's messagefactory
and it print out this warning. seems ok.